# Conditions under which $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

What are the conditions such that $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$, where $(a, b, c)$ are nonzero integers ?

Comment: something to start with $a+b$ and $c$ must be relatively prime. Indeed if $d$ was a factor of both $a+b$ and $c$ then it is a factor of $a+b+c$ and of $abc$ but not of $1-abc$.

Answer (score 3):

The triples $(a,b,c)$ with the property that $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$ can be characterized as triples $(a,b,d-a-b)$, where $d$ is a divisor of $1+ab(a+b)$.  This is because $a+b+c=d$ for such triples, while

$$1-abc=1-ab(d-a-b)=1+ab(a+b)-abd$$

For example, if $a=b=4$, we have $1+ab(a+b)=129$, which has $8$ divisors:  $d=\pm1,\pm3,\pm43$ and $\pm129$, giving triples

$$\begin{align}
&(4,4,-7)\\
&(4,4,-9)\\
&(4,4,-5)\\
&(4,4,-11)\\
&(4,4,35)\\
&(4,4,-51)\\
&(4,4,121)\\
&(4,4,-137)
\end{align}$$