# If $\gcd(a+b,c)=1$ and $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$, does it follow that $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$ or $b\mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is it true that:                                                                 For any integers $(\mid a\mid, \mid b \mid, \mid c\mid) \geq 2$ such that $\gcd(a+b,c)=1$, if $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$ then one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is a multiple of another ?

Comment: Related: [Conditions under which $a+b+c$ divides $1-abc$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1586758)

Comment: Well, the responses to that particular post seem not say much about the solution being sought in this one. That is why i rephrased it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take $a=5, b=7, c=409$,

then $a+b+c=421$ divides $1-abc=-14314$ and $\text{gcd}(12, 409)=1$;

but neither of $a, b, c$ divides another.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Take

$$a = -3,$$
$$b = 2,$$
$$c = 2.$$

Comment: Well, by $a\mid b$ i simply wanted to state that one of the variables $(a,b,c)$ divides the other, which is satisfied by your example since $2\mid 2$. Maybe the question wasn't clear at first, but i have since edited it.